# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'showBarChart' of undefined in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, nvd3.js

I have a function that customizes tooltip of `nvd3` `scatterChart` plot. In the function I want to update state, so I am calling another function that does `setState`:

```
chart.tooltip.contentGenerator(function (d) {
      var html = "<div>";
      d.series.forEach(function(elem){
        Object.keys(data_obj).forEach(function(key_1) {
          var outer_obj = data_obj[key_1];
          if (outer_obj["key"] === elem.key) {
             // THIS FUNCTION UPDATES STATE
             this.showBarChart(elem.key);

              var expr = outer_obj["values"][0]["expr"];
              html += "<p>" + elem.key + "</p>";
              html += "<p>x = " + d.value + ", y = " + elem.value + "</p>";
          }
        });
      })
      html += "</div>";
      return html;
    }).bind(this);
```

Inside the constructor I have:

```
class ScatterChart extends React.Component {
  constructor(props){
  super(props);
  this.createScatterChart = this.createScatterChart.bind(this);
  this.showBarChart = this.showBarChart.bind(this);
  this.state = {
      neuron_name: ""
  }
}
```

And `render`:

```
render() {
console.log(this.state.neuron_name);
  return <div width={500} height={500}>
          <svg ref={node => this.node = node} width={500} height={500}></svg>
          <BarChart datum = { expressionDatum.getDatumForNeuron(this.state.neuron_name) }/>
        </div>
}
```

How could I make `contentGenerator` function see `this` object?

Comment: It's hard to tell what you're trying to do / asking but maybe this `chart.tooltip.contentGenerator(function (d) {` to `chart.tooltip.contentGenerator( (d) => {`

Comment: I tried that and `this` is still `undefined`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to set the state by assigning `that = this` and then accessing `that`:

```
 var that = this;
    chart.tooltip.contentGenerator(function (d) {
      var html = "<div>";
      d.series.forEach(function(elem){
        Object.keys(data_obj).forEach(function(key_1) {
          var outer_obj = data_obj[key_1];
          if (outer_obj["key"] === elem.key) {
              that.showBarChart(elem.key);
              var expr = outer_obj["values"][0]["expr"];
              html += "<p>" + elem.key + "</p>";
              html += "<p>x = " + d.value + ", y = " + elem.value + "</p>";

          }
        });
      })
      html += "</div>";
      return html;
    });
```

Although it lead to a weird bug when `nvd3` prints `tooltips` like crazy, I can update the state.

Comment: I think your issue was that you put .bind(this) outside the parentheses. It should've been }.bind(this));