# NVD3 tooltip bug

Tags: javascript, reactjs, nvd3.js

I was able to solve the question: [Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'showBarChart' of undefined in React](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47999062/uncaught-typeerror-cannot-read-property-showbarchart-of-undefined-in-react)

```
var that = this;
chart.tooltip.contentGenerator(function (d) {
      var html = "<div>";
      d.series.forEach(function(elem){
        Object.keys(data_obj).forEach(function(key_1) {
          var outer_obj = data_obj[key_1];
          if (outer_obj["key"] === elem.key) {
              that.showBarChart(elem.key);
              var expr = outer_obj["values"][0]["expr"];
              html += "<p>" + elem.key + "</p>";
              html += "<p>x = " + d.value + ", y = " + elem.value + "</p>";
          }
        });
      })
      html += "</div>";
      return html;
    });
```

However, the solution led to a very weird bug in `nvd3` `scatterChart` when the `tooltip` does not go away on `mouse out` and just stays on the page.

[image]

How could I fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was that in `componentDidUpdate` I was calling `createScatterChart`. I commented it out and it started to work fine. It was happening apparently because of `React` workflow that I found to be described in the question: [Trace why a React component is re-rendering](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41004631/trace-why-a-react-component-is-re-rendering)

```
componentDidMount() {
 this.createScatterChart()
}

 componentDidUpdate() {
 //this.createScatterChart()
}
```

`Calling this.setState() within the component. This will trigger the following component lifecycle methods shouldComponentUpdate > componentWillUpdate > render > componentDidUpdate`

Comment: I've gotta ask - why are you using NVD3 with React rather than React specific implementations of D3?

Comment: Could you send some libraries of React-D3? I think there could be less code written by me if I use NVD3, so I am trying to do less work. Honestly, I am not completely sure, but that is what I am thinking for now.

Comment: https://emeeks.github.io/semiotic/#/semiotic/examples

http://nivo.rocks/#/

https://uber.github.io/react-vis/

http://formidable.com/open-source/victory/gallery/